# CLIPS using variable as a name of instance

Tags: clips, expert-system

can I use variable as a name of instance?
Example:

`(make-instance [?input] (name)(age))`

Answer (score 1):

The name slot of an instance is predefined and stores the instance name, so when creating an instance you wouldn't specify it twice using the make-instance function. Otherwise, here's the syntax for using a variable to specify an instance name:

```
         CLIPS (6.31 6/12/19)
CLIPS> 
(defclass PERSON
   (is-a USER)
   (slot full-name)
   (slot age))
CLIPS> (bind ?input p1)
p1
CLIPS> 
(make-instance ?input of PERSON
   (full-name "John Doe")
   (age 23))
[p1]
CLIPS> (send [p1] print)
[p1] of PERSON
(full-name "John Doe")
(age 23)
CLIPS>
```